# How to process a large matrix of size 28x28x11684?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I'm having 11684 matrices each of size 28x28. So the variable a has size 28x28x11684. Now i would like to do sorting them using a for loop on each matrix of 28x28 and store it in a variable z. Here is my code

```
for i=1:11684
    z=sort(a(:,:,i));
end
```

When i run the code, it is giving me the variable z of size 28x28. But i want the variable z to be of size 28x28x11684. Plese help me.

Comment: `z` should be multipaged like `a`.  `z(:,:,i) = ...` or something like that.

Comment: If the posted answers solve your problem, consider marking the most helpful one as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of the answer so that we may know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any loop at all. [**`sort`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) is directly applicable on multi-dimensional arrays as well.

```
z = sort(a);
```

This is it!

Comment: Isn't `sort(a,3)` needed here, since it otherwise sorts, and thus scrambles, the 28x28 matrices as well?

Comment: @Adriaan The problem that OP is having (apparently, as I understand it) is the variable `z` being overwritten in each iteration. In the question, the sorting is actually applied on the first dimension (and separately on each 3D slice).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that sort will sort the columns. This is how you do it:

```
a=rand(28,28,55);
z=a*0;
for i=1:size(a,3)
    z(:,:,i)=sort(a(:,:,i));
end
```

Comment: `z=a*0` is slightly obfuscated; `z=zeros(size(a))` is what one'd normally use.